# No animation ScrollToAsync on ScrollView

Tags: xamarin, scroll, uwp, scrollview

I have next code:

```
async void Start(object sender, EventArgs e){
        await ScrollContainer.ScrollToAsync(0,500,true);
}
```

It is good work on UWP Desktop, but it isn't work on my Windows Mobile (real device) - scrollview position is change, but no animation effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still using the WinRT extensions on the scrollviewer to have more control over the animation...

Bit long to post the code here on StackO, it is a series of extensions.

But you can [see it here...](https://github.com/AppCreativity/Kliva/blob/master/src/Kliva/Extensions/ScrollViewerExtensions.cs)

And an example [usage here...](https://github.com/AppCreativity/Kliva/blob/590dbd3a14b068348f4cfa0d485854eef2164c45/src/Kliva/Controls/ActivityFeedControl.xaml.cs#L241)